# Aliasing links to files in Drupal 7

Tags: file, drupal, url-rewriting, drupal-7

I have a problem with my Drupal website.

1. I have links in bodies of book pages, which link to a file.
   What I want to change is, that the URL that is showed, should look different, instead of: `sites/default/files/../../file.pdf`
   I want something like `documents/file.pdf`
   How to do that?
2. I also want to do this with uploaded/attached files, I downloaded the modules file aliases, but it doesn't seem as it works?

Does anyone of you have an idea or already did this, and could explain me how to do that?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The alias module only allows redirects to paths that Drupal recognizes as legitimate. That includes all menu items created through built-in or custom modules. However, you can't make an alias to a file because Drupal isn't aware of the file as a valid path. (Drupal doesn't look in file folders to validate paths, but rather its own internal menu validation system.)

To get around this, you can use the Global Redirect module (see https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect), where you can create a redirect from any path to any page (internal to your site or external). Because of the freedom to redirect to any page, you can include paths to files.

Be forewarned that you must add a redirect directive (default is 301), which can instruct certain browsers to update bookmarks and such. This is probably what you want, but take a moment to research 301 redirects to make sure you understand the implications. With a file link, I wouldn't worry too much, especially because it's unlikely to get into a sandbox search engine situation (search "google sandbox effect" for an explanation).

Answer (score 0):

The most robust solution would be to use your own `.htaccess` rules to expand or shorten the path. Doing this from inside of Drupal could mess up a lot of file links.

I encountered the problem on moving multi-domain installations; maybe looking for anwsers on this topic will unearth more tips.

Drupal actually has some sort of abstracted file handler which for example the [CDN](https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn) system uses – I just don't know how to address this via simple measures.

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink on your webserver.

```
ln -s sites/default/files/../../ documents
```

This won't break the existing path, but will allow the documents to be accessed via the http://[yoursite]/documents path.